# Postgres select query runs slow when using JDBC but quick when running it in PSQL from the same server

Tags: postgresql, database-performance, query-performance

I have the following, pretty simple, query that I am running using JDBC that is taking an excessive amount of time to run. The database is an AWS RDS server. The rt2 table has about 600K entries and the CM2 table about 300K.  The query returns 11230 rows.

```
SELECT cm2.target 
from sysmgmt.sys_root rt2 
   join cmgmt.member cm2 on cm2.cmid = rt2.cmid and cm2.version=rt2.work_version_id 
where rt2.tid=1001 
  and rt2.proj='d791194b-f2b7-42a7-aba7-f879e052e59d'::uuid 
  and rt2.deleted = false 
  and cm2.tid=1001 and cm2.proj = 'd791194b-f2b7-42a7-aba7-f879e052e59d'::uuid;
```

When I run this query with the JDBC call it takes 40 seconds!  However, if I run this exact same query in a PSQL command line on the same machine it is almost instantaneous.

Running EXPLAIN ANALYZE shows the following plan.

```
Nested Loop  (cost=0.85..7.77 rows=1 width=176) (actual time=0.030..36.067 rows=11230 loops=1)
->  Index Scan using m_cell_tid_proj_version_idx on member cm2  (cost=0.42..3.32 rows=1 width=197) (actual time=0.020..2.988 rows=11230 loops=1)
    Index Cond: ((tid = '1001'::numeric) AND (proj = 'ed1a7c79-a3a1-4d8e-815b-0fbbcbd7bf4b'::uuid))
->  Index Scan using sys_root_cmid_workversion_idx on sys_root rt2  (cost=0.42..4.45 rows=1 width=21) (actual time=0.002..0.002 rows=1 loops=11230)
    Index Cond: ((cmid = cm2.cmid) AND (work_version_id = cm2.version))
    Filter: ((NOT deleted) AND (tid = '1001'::numeric) AND (proj = 'ed1a7c79-a3a1-4d8e-815b-0fbbcbd7bf4b'::uuid))
Planning Time: 0.374 ms
Execution Time: 36.499 ms
```

Some things I have tried to speed it up.

- rearrange the query
- Adding indexes that match better
- Change fillfactor (didn't seem to have any effect)
- VACUUM

None of these seem to have any effect.  The java code is pretty straight forward, run the query and then iterate over the results.  The timing is taken just before executeQuery and just after it.

```
  Took :[40644.067138] Comment:found 11230 SQL Query:[SELECT cm2.target from sysmgmt.sys_root rt2 join mgmt.member cm2 on cm2.cmid = rt2.cmid and cm2.version=rt2.work_version_id where rt2.tid=1001 and rt2.proj='ed1a7c79-a3a1-4d8e-815b-0fbbcbd7bf4b'::uuid and cm2.tid=1001 and cm2.proj = 'ed1a7c79-a3a1-4d8e-815b-0fbbcbd7bf4b'::uuid and rt2.deleted = false]
```

There are about 5 to 10 other queries that are running in the same transaction, is it possible that the other queries cause an issue downstream to when it gets to this query?

If anyone has any ideas on what might be the problem, I would appreciate some insight.

Comment: How much data needs to come down?  Assuming it's a `text` column, you can `select sum(length(cm2.target))` in psql.

Comment: How exactly are you passing the parameters from within your Java code?

Comment: The query has a few "?" parameters and are being set with the following commands.  
selectLockItems.setLong(i++, tId); 
selectLockItems.setObject(i++, projId); //rt2
selectLockItems.setLong(i++, tId); //cm2

Comment: Using sum(length(cm2.target)) returned with 1931560

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I missed tagging you on my comment.  Thanks for cleaning up the plan formatting

Comment: @MikeOrganek I missed tagging you.  It is a text column and the size does not seem outrageous.  Running PSQL on the same box comes back instantaneously.

Comment: How tight to the query is the java code that emits the log message with the timing info.  Can you post that block?  If not, can you please make sure that the timing measures from immediately before `executeQuery()` to immediately after?

Comment: Can you use auto_explain to capture the execution plan of the query the way it is executed via JDBC?

Comment: @MikeOrganek  The timing is aroung the query.  42 seconds.   double start = System.nanoTime();
    String query = selectLockContents.toString();
    ResultSet lockMembers = null;
    try {
              lockMembers = selectLockContents.executeQuery();
     logPerformance( "execute only",start,query);

Comment: Can you please try adding another logged query that is your original but wrapped with `select count(*) from (<original query>) as o` and see how long that takes to execute?  I know it's less than 2MB retrieved (172 bytes per row), but this should help isolate whether the slowdown is in the server or in the client.

Comment: @jjanes thanks for the suggestion on auto_explain. I turned it on and it confirms that it is using the same explain plan as posted in the description.  It also says it is taking 42 seconds to run.  Even with all index scans.

Comment: @MikeOrganek  I added the "select count(cm2.target) call just before the real call.  The "count" call took 55ms.  The "real" call just after it took "192 ms" !!  Is there something special that needs to be done with prepared statements?

Comment: I assume you are using it correctly as it is pretty difficult to get wrong :-)  This sounds to me like an infrastructure problem that has nothing to do with your code.  It could be that parts of your postgres service have to be read in from swap, contention for postgres's disk, network connectivity (typically firewall) problems, or a combination of those.

Comment: @MikeOrganek I took the "Count" back out, and now it works fine.  Not feeling confident.  This is on AWS RDS which has been interesting to work with.  It's just strange that it manifested in this one query repeatedly.  Thanks for the ideas!

Comment: @ToddPatch is any of the tables created at runtime during your execution of data inserted during the transaction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that the Explain Analyze plan was different when it was being run in in the context of the activity.  Turning up the auto_explain parameters and having it log to the postgres log files showed that the plan was different than when I ran it as a standalone request.  The question then became "how to get it to do the right thing?".  The answer to that was to turn up the default_statistics_target to 200 from 100 and run ANALYZE on the database. I also rearranged the join table order.  In doing both of these, the problem has gone away (for good hopefully).  This wiki https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Performance_Optimization also proved to be a great resource.

Comment: "*I also rearranged the join table order.*"  I doubt that changed anything